# Can't declare variable in stored procedure phpmyadmin | mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I wanted to create a stored procedure that has a variable in it, so I made this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPTest()
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var INT;
END
```

But it gave me an error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@var INT' at line 3
```

I've tried all the answer from stackoverflow, I'm using phpmyadmin version 4.5.4.1 and it says up to date. How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use [delimiter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html):

```
delimiter 
CREATE PROCEDURE SPTest()
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var INT;
END
| 
delimiter ;
```

Comment: It still gives me an error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE SPTest()
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @var INT;
 END
 delimiter' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is twofold; the use of `@` in the variable name doesn't seem to be supported by MySQL, which is compounded by an apparent [phpMyAdmin bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11979) which is causing phpMyAdmin to fail even if the SQL is valid.

I had luck at the command line using this statement:

```
DELIMITER &
CREATE PROCEDURE SPTest()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v INT;
END
&
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Routine just add BEGIN and END

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 1;
END
```

i hope it will work.